# Is there a mathematical connection between Causal Fermion Systems and Noncommutative geometry?

Tags: non-commutative-geometry

Well, the title says it all.
 Upon research, many of the ideas in Felix Finster's Causal Fermion Systems (CFS) and Alain Connes' Noncommutative geometry (NCG) struck me as similar. Both theories involve triples that encode the underlying geometry, from the "objects on it" (more or less). Both concepts provide ways to encode the Standard model, and reproduce general relativity via some action (NCG's *spectral* action and CFS's *causal* action), and even reproducing aspects of quantum field theory. Also, their descriptions of fermions seem similar.

I've only been able to find a mere sentence about their connection, which said essentially that in CFS, the wavefunctions are the objects, which has no correspondence in NCG, but I'm still not 100% convinced.

**Is there a mathematical connection between these two concepts (particularly a spectral triple and a causal fermion system)?**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_fermion_system#Definition_of_a_causal_fermion_system

Comment: Finster briefly comments on this "frequently asked question" on p. 182-183 of his https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.04742